# WooCommerce Price Sorting

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

The default Sort by Price function (high to low and low to high) in WooCommerce has problems when there is a mix of simple and variable products. I think it is taking a very literal view of pricing. When sorting from high to low, it is grabbing the highest price (simple or variable) for every product. The same for lowest price sorting. We are showing the lowest price variation for each variable product by using the "Default Form Values" setting for variable products.

It isn’t basing the sort on the currently listed price of the product - which I've modified the default output of Woo to show the lowest price variation instead of a range.

Here is an example:

https://basketballgoalstore.com/in-ground-hoops/?swoof=1&orderby=price-desc&pa_backboard-size=72&really_curr_tax=1404-product_cat

Look at the third product, the Goalsetter MVP and its price when sorting the price high to low and then low to high.

This appears to be an oversight in WooCommerce. I've already have a thread in the WordPress.org Support > Plugin: WooCommerce forum without any good answers.

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/woocommerce-product-sorting-by-price/#post-10249583

Any ideas on how to fix this.

Thanks